# Convert XMl code to java code with expression

Tags: java, xml-binding

```
<date-time>2008-07-13T18:00:00</date-time>
```

Comment: What about a little more information? What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're looking for something like this:

```
String pattern = "'<date-time>'yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'</date-time>'";
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
Date date = format.parse("<date-time>2008-07-13T18:00:00</date-time>");
```